# Multiple instances of Kafka on same host

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm attempting to run 2 instances of Kafka on the same host. In order to achieve this, I download and extract Kafka and create a copy of the extracted Kafka folder and contents, creating two Kafka instances: Kafka-instance-1 and Kafka-instance-2.

I do not want to create a multiple broker setup within the same cluster, just 1 broker within each Kafka instance.

I update `server.properties` on Kafka-instance-1 &  Kafka-instance-2 to each point at different ports. So instead of the default port 9092, I use 8182. As I've started working on this I'm wondering if this is possible in Kafka - running two instances on the same machines, again to reiterate I'm not attempting to run two brokers but two independent Kafka instances. Are there pitfalls to attempting this? One thing that concerns me is that perhaps Kafka is using ports that are not exposed via config which will prevent multiple instances executing on the same machine.

Will this or any other problems be encountered trying to set up two Kafka instances on the same host ?

The reason I'm doing this is that I'm testing an app. The app requires its own set of topics. To test multiple instances of the app at the same time each app instance requires it's topic's to not be written to by other running instances of the app. For this reason, each app will have it's own Kafka instance. I could install Kafka on multiple machines and point each app to its own machine but that is extra work and is far easier to just create multiple Kafka instances on the same machine, that is if it's doable.

Comment: "app requires its own set of topics" ... And these topics cannot be separate names on the same, single, cluster?

Comment: The documentation used to describe how to start two instances: https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/#quickstart_multibroker

Comment: @OneCricketeer I don’t think a multi broker setup will work in this case as each app uses the same set of topics and is required to have access to the topics in isolation. The reason for this requirement is a long story but primarily due to the architecture of the system. If I could create a set of topics for specific broker and each app instance points to its own dedicated broker then this would suffice but I don’t think this is possible in Kafka ? To put it more simply, how can two processes write to two topics in parallel where each topic has the same name ?

Comment: Are the topic names hard-coded? In almost all Kafka applications I've worked on, the topics are configurable and the application is responsible for ensuring the topics get created and configured at startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have an easier time of your general development and testing if you use something like Docker to host your brokers, because it makes it much easier to spin up and isolate instances.

But,  you can have multiple isolated instances of the Kafka broker running on a single machine if you want. As you say you need to allocate a separate listener port, as you've done. Make sure they're writing to different `log.dirs` paths too. If you're sharing a Zookeeper then I think you'll need to specify a [unique `chroot`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_zookeeper.connect) for each instance as well.